# codeigniter active record join 2 databases

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, join

Can I use a `$this->db->join('database.table')` without inserting the second parameter of this function? I need to connect 2 databases, but they dont have nothing that binds them. I know that it works with SQL because I have tried it, however I want to change the model using active record, because I find it more flexible etc.. but I dont know how to insert **the join**

```
$this->db->select('users.user_id');
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('user_detail', 'users.user_id = user_detail.id', 'left');
```

and now something like:

```
$this->db->join('cities.city');
```

So the SQL should be like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.user_id FROM users LEFT JOIN .... JOIN cities.city
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.user_id FROM users LEFT JOIN .... JOIN cities.city ON
```

What I actually have.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. If you look at the CI core files, you will see that `ON` will always be passed. I didn't realize this was the case until I checked the system files.

```
$join = $type.'JOIN '.$this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE).' ON '.$cond;
```

Reference in `/system/database/DB_active_rec.php` line 340. Even in the [latest version (GitHub)](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/b61affdfeb37da0e97fc33a8ffe3ccabb0e47e04/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L501) this is still the case, although either `ON` or `USING()` will be used.

Your best bet is to just use `$this->db->query()`:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT users.user_id FROM users LEFT JOIN .... JOIN cities.city');
```

**Update:** Since you are using 2.1.3, you can hack the core files (since I do not believe there is a way to extend CI active records). Although you shouldn't edit core files on a normal basis, at least this will give you what you need. Open `/system/database/DB_active_rec.php`:

Change line 310 to:

```
public function join($table, $cond, $type = '', $use_on = TRUE)
```

Change line 340 to (which now becomes 2 lines):

```
$on_cond = ($use_on === TRUE) ? ' ON '.$cond : NULL;
$join = $type.'JOIN '.$this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE).$on_cond;
```

Now in your model when you call your `join()` pass a 4th parameter, `FALSE`, to turn off the `ON`:

```
$this->db->join('cities.city', NULL, '', FALSE);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I have tried it, but the problem is that I have multiple joins (12) thats why I want to use active record. Can I somehow use the active record at first, then combine it with the SQL and then again add to it some active record statements?

Comment: What version of CI are you using?

Comment: my CI version is 2.1.3